# How to use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to find the not hyper linked text

Tags: php, dom

I want to parse html to a dom tree, and find all the text NOT inside the `<a>` tags, so, I googled it, and found "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser". It seems it can help me to parse the HTML DOM to a DOM Tree. I would like to find the text NOT inside `<a>` tags, but I only can find the element which is inside `<a>` tag.  *ps: it don't support the CSS3 not selector yet. Thank you. 
Any one experience on this? Thank you.

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org). Also see [Best methods or parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I hope I'm not misunderstanding the question, but can't you use the built-in DOM functions for PHP to find the text inside the `<a>` tags?</strike>

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://blahblah.com/blah.html");
$elem_list = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($elem_list as $elem)
    echo $elem->textContent;
```

In that case I would remove all `<a>` tags and their contents (for example with regular expressions) and then load the resulting HTML into your DOM parser of choice.

**Update**: Even better, immediately parse the HTML and use the built-in functions to remove the `<a>` tags, or loop through all tags and just skip the `<a>` tags. Regex with HTML should be avoided.

Comment: Oh, ok. The question text was a little misleading, tried to correct it (my edits need to be peer reviewed), hope that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this class many times. Its an excellent solution to parse html/dom in php.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load your html as string
$html->load('........ HTML ..........');
$a = $html->find('a');
$text='';
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
$text.=$a[$i]->innertext;
```

variable $text containing all the text in a tags.
Hope it will help you.